# Java SE 1.8 disappears after installation in MacOS Mojave

Tags: java, macos

Download from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html, choose "Java SE Development Kit 8u231" for Mac.

I can install Java SE 1.8 successfully, also added this to .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Start a new terminal, "java -version" gives proper info.

The problem is, after certain period of time (not sure, say 1 hour), "java -version" would return error, cannot find java and ask me install again. If i do "which java", it's there.
Reinstall fixes it, then happens again after some time.

Seems there're similar posts on this, but not sure if my case is a little bit different, since it did install successfully in the beginning.

Any suggestions ? Thx !

Answer (score 0):

ok, it's our company policy, i downloaded the java version online, which is not approved by our IT.
After installed the IT approved version, it's working now.